# .htaccess file configuration with php and html websites on the same server

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, cakephp, mod-rewrite

I recently uploaded a new cakePHP website to my server which is working well, however two other html websites that were previously working well have stopped working. The two websites are within folders on the root of my server. I suspect it is it due to the new htaccess file. Does anyone have any suggestions of what updates are needed to the .htaccess file? See the current htaccess code below, and below that the errors each of my html sites are showing. Many thanks!!!

---

### .htaccess code:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
   RewriteEngine on
   RewriteRule    ^$ app/webroot/    [L]
   RewriteRule    (.*) app/webroot/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

---

### HTML website error messages:

Internal Server Error

The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request.

Please contact the server administrator and inform them of the time the error occurred, and the actions you performed just before this error.

More information about this error may be available in the server error log.

---

Comment: Check your logs for that problem.

Comment: Hi Stony, thanks for your reply. Apologies but am a newbie, which "logs" do you mean, and any tips about what I should be checking in the "logs"?

Comment: Your apache log /var/log/apache2/error.log for example if you use linux.

Comment: Hi Stoney. My hosting is Linux, but I don't have such a directory. Thanks for trying to help though.

Comment: Then you search that files. Sometimes there is a log folder in your root directory given by your hoster.

Answer (score 2):

You need to add the htaccess file in your html folder with the following code

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine Off
</IfModule>
```